# How to convert background color of png files in each subfolder using Imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

I'm trying to convert background color of png files in each subfolders.

I tried code like this in windows cmd.

```
cd /d G:\pic\kmz mogrify convert -fuzz 10% -transparent black *.png
```

but it failed.

there are lots of png files in each subfolder of kmz folder.

Please help.

Comment: You will have to loop over each subdirectory. Mogrify does not traverse the directory structure. It only works on the main directory.

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36986436/how-to-batch-resize-millions-of-images-to-fit-a-max-width-and-height/36986701#36986701

Comment: See http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=25862&p=156904&hilit=mogrify#p156904 for an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll look like this:

```
CD /D G:\pic
FOR /R kmz\ %%G IN (*.PNG) DO (mogrify -fuzz 10%% -transparent black "%%G")
```

---

If you have v7 or newer of **ImageMagick**, you'll need to prefix `mogrify` with `magick` like this:

```
FOR /R kmz\ %%G IN (*.PNG) DO (magick mogrify -fuzz 10%% -transparent black "%%G")
```